# Check if element of linked list exists

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to determine if the value is a member in the link. if it is a member, it will return true otherwise it returns false. I try to do this

```
public boolean member(Integer val){
    if(node.val.equals(val) || node.next.val.equals(val)){
        System.out.println("true");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, it only check the value of the head and value of the next of the head. What would be other way to check the value of all node?

Comment: Where does `node` come from? Is it an inner method?

Comment: You'll have to use a loop to look at all values in the list. Tutorial: [The while and do-while Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: Best not to use a linked list if you need to ask this question regularly as it's a slow operation. Use a set instead.

Comment: node is an inner class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass the root node and loop through your linkedList:

```
public boolean member(Node root, Integer val){
    Node currentNode = root;//keep track of current node
    while(currentNode != null){
        //switched currentNode.val and val to avoid null pointer exceptions
        if(val.equals(currentNode.val)){
        //if you're looking for nulls...still with the original
        //if(currentNode.val.equals(val)){
            System.out.println("true");
            return true;
        }
        currentNode = currentNode.next();//update current node
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Sorry, I wrote this in literally 20 seconds.  Should be good now

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik updatttttttttttttttttted

Comment: Better use `val.equals(currentNode.val)` to avoid `NPE` if `currentNode.val` is `null`.

Comment: @sp00m Unless the caller is searching for `null`!

Comment: @sp00m I was thinking about the null pointer case, but OP hasn't mentioned how he wants to handle that.  I'm just assuming everything is set in place.

Comment: @sp00m If you allow the existence of null-entries, then you must allow searching for null-entries. Mohammad's code assumes nulls are not allowed, and that's a fair assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Ok without recursion:

```
public boolean member(Integer val){
  Node current = node;
  while (current != null) {
    if (current.val.equals(val)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      current = current.next;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Recursion is really unneccessary. Either simply cycle through it or use `contains()` method..

Comment: Inefficient for large lists in Java.  No tail recursion.

Comment: Avoid recursions when you can. You can, avoid it.

Comment: Sorry guys, I edited it ;-) Sorry for all the confussion with my double posts lol

Comment: No I deleted the other one, it's still displaying??

Comment: Ah, OK. It just needed a refresh. But yes, it remains visible to everyone, just with a red bacground.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses a Boolean function to determine if element exists in linked list.

```
    public boolean doesValExist(int value){
    Node traveler = head;
    while(traveler != null){
        if(traveler.getElement() == value){
            return true;
        }
        traveler = traveler.getNext();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code..

```
boolean exists = linkedList.contains("element");    
System.out.println("element exists in LinkedList ? : " + exists);
```

Comment: I guess he's writing his own LinkedList.. Your solution is irrelevant.

Comment: That would work for the built-in `LinkedList`.  But I don't think that's what the OP is using.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    if (s.length() == 0) {
        rvFriendsList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rvSearch_Friends.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        FriendsType ="actual";
    }
    if (s.length() >= 1) {
        FriendsType ="search";
        rvFriendsList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rvSearch_Friends.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rvSearch_Friends.bringToFront();
        btnCancel.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        String searchString = s.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        Log.d("@w2w2w2w", "" + searchString);
        int realtext = searchString.length();
        linkedList_SearchUser.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < linkList_GetAllContacts.size(); i++) {
            String currentString = linkList_GetAllContacts.get(i).get("first_name").toString();
            if (realtext <= currentString.length()) {
                if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(currentString.substring(0, realtext))) {
                    linkedList_SearchUser.add(linkList_GetAllContacts.get(i));
                    hype1 = new Custom_Adapter_GetAllContacts((Activity) context, linkedList_SearchUser);
                    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
                    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                    rvSearch_Friends.setLayoutManager(llm);
                    rvSearch_Friends.setAdapter(hype1);
                }
            } else {
                hype1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are not incrementing the node value at the end of the loop . Also do a null check to check the end .

```
        public boolean member(Integer val){
            if(node.next!=null){
            if(node.val.equals(val) || node.next.val.equals(val)){
                System.out.println("true");
                node = node.next; // incrementing the node value 
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
    if( node.val.equals(val)){
    return true;
    }
else{
return false;
}
    }
```

Comment: @downvoter , why the downvote , a comment on the error would be much appreciated